# Determine whether the series $\Sigma$$n^ka^n/n!$ converges or diverges

Tags: calculus

Well I know the series converges, I just wanted to make sure I did the work properly.
I used the ratio test.

I ended up with $(n+1)^{(k-1)}a/n^k$.
I concluded that the exponent $k>k-1$ and so the denominator is bigger than the numerator making $L<1$ which means the series converges.

Is this correct, or can I not assume the denominator is bigger than the numerator?

and thanks in advance!!:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

$$\frac{(n+1)^ka^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}\cdot\frac{n!}{n^ka^n}=\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^k\frac{a}{n+1}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}\ldots$$

But I think Marvis's answer's more elegant, honest.

Comment: +1. I was adding the same thing to my answer as well :).

Comment: @DonAntonio thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Note that
$$f(a) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{n^k a^n}{n!} = \underbrace{\left(a\dfrac{d}{da} \left(a\dfrac{d}{da} \left(a\dfrac{d}{da} \left(\cdots \left(a\dfrac{d}{da} e^a\right) \right) \right) \right) \right)}_{\text{The operator $a \frac{d}{da}$ acts $n$ times on $e^a$}}$$
Hence, the radius of convergence is $\infty$.

---

Also, by ratio test, we have
$$\limsup_{n \to \infty} \dfrac{(n+1)^ka^{n+1}}{(n+1)!} \cdot \dfrac{n!}{n^k a^n} = \limsup_{n \to \infty} \left(1+\dfrac1n \right)^k\dfrac{a}{(n+1)} = 0$$
Hence, the series converges for all $a \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Very nice indeed +1

Comment: i don't understand how you got $1+(1/n)^k$ ?

Comment: @lawlipop $\dfrac{(n+1)^k}{n^k} = \left(1+\dfrac1n \right)^k$

Comment: @Marvis oh can't believe i didnt see that lol, thanks now i understand!! :)